# how to print jasper report in Eclipse RCP using its print option?

Tags: eclipse, printing, jasper-reports, rcp

My question : I have a ViewerComposite in Eclipse RCP application which displays Jasper Report (*.jrxml) integrated into it. The report displayed in this ViewerComposite can be exported as PDF,RTF,XML,jrxml,HTML,CSV, etc. Everything is fine except I can not print this report by using the print option provided at top of ViewerComposite in GUI. How can I print the reports by using my default printer by using print option of the report viewer.
Rem: I can print jasper report by using the print option of jasper report viewer composite in Oracle JDeveloper Projects without adding any more codes(by default).

Comment: I solved my problem myself after 4 hours on what to do. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way for me to make my Jasper Reports in Eclipse RCP application was as follows :

1. replace the ViewerComposite (i.e. com.jasperassistant.designer.viewer.ViewerComposite.ViewerComposite) by SWT/AWT composite and JRViewer (net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer) first.
2. set the generated JasperPrint document onto the JRViewer object.
3. add the JRViewer object onto the ContentPane of this SWT/AWT composite.
4. run the report and check printing and exporting the report data into allowed formats ie.(*.PDF,*.ODT,*.docx,*.jrxml,*.jasper,*.xml,*.html,*.xls etc); all will work.

The details code for this is as follows :

```java
//generate the jaspser print document
JasperPrint jprint = generateReport(id, nepFromDate, nepToDate);

//initialize JRViewer object 
JRViewer jasperviewer = new JRViewer(jprint);

//add the SWT_AWT compposite for SWING contents of GUI              
final Composite swtAwtComposite = new Composite(comTBReport, SWT.EMBEDDED);
swtAwtComposite.setBounds(10, 0, 767, 600);

Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(swtAwtComposite);

Panel panel = new Panel();
frame.add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

JRootPane rootPane = new JRootPane();
rootPane.setSize(767, 600);
panel.add(rootPane);

//Define a container yourself
Container c = rootPane.getContentPane();

//Add the JRViewer object onto the container to render in GUI
c.add(jasperviewer);
```